# Warning: Use of undefined constant list_all - assumed 'list_all' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Tags: plugins, php

I have a problem with php 7 syntax.
I installed this plugin called simple table manager
https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-table-manager/

and upon activation I got these warnings

> Warning: Use of undefined constant list_all - assumed 'list_all' (this will throw an Error in a
>   future version of PHP) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wp2\wp-content\plugins\simple-table-manager\controller.php
>   on line 52
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant add_new - assumed 'add_new' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) ....
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant settings - assumed 'settings' (this
>   will throw an Error.....
>
> Warning: Use of undefined constant edit - assumed 'edit' (this will
>   throw an Error.....

the code looks something like this

```
class Controller {
....

public function add_menu() {
        add_menu_page('Simple Table Manager - List', 'Simple Table Manager', 'manage_options', $this->slug['list'], array($this, list_all ));
        add_submenu_page(null, 'Simple Table Manager - Add New', 'Add New', 'manage_options', $this->slug['add'], array($this, add_new));
        add_submenu_page($this->slug['list'], 'Simple Table Manager - Settings', 'Settings', 'manage_options', $this->slug['settings'], array($this, settings));
        add_submenu_page(null, 'Simple Table Manager - Edit', 'Edit', 'manage_options', $this->slug['edit'], array($this, edit));
    }
public function list_all() {....}
public function add_new() {...}
public function edit() {...}
public function settings() {...}

}
```

I have php 7, I'm assuming the syntax used by the developer of the plugin is obsolete

so basically the 4 variables giving errors are actually other functions(methods) of the class itself. what is the correct way to call these methods?
I tried 
 array($this, $this->add_new)
but it didn't work

I will appreciate it if can help with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in this code:

```
    add_menu_page('Simple Table Manager - List', 'Simple Table Manager', 'manage_options', $this->slug['list'], array($this, list_all ));
```

The part `array($this, list_all )` is a function callback, but there should be name of a function passed as string as second item in the array. So it should be:

```
array($this, 'list_all' )
```

PS. It should have been a problem with earlier versions of PHP too...

Comment: I don't know how to thank you enough! I'm new to php, I thought I should just add () since it was a function, but I was wrong. Thanks a lot